Why is there so much salt in cheese?
I want to reduce my salt intake for health reasons, especially from processed products such as cheese. I am aware is the crucial role that salt plays in the preservation of meat, it is not there just for flavour. Cheesemaking however does not rely on salt in the same way, and at least the simple young cheeses can be made perfectly well without any salt, even if their taste is not as good as with salt added.
Why does commercial cheese contain so much salt?  It is purely a question of taste preferences, or does it play a functional role in commercial cheese production?

Hey everybody, I just had to delete some comments. A reminder: 1) we don't discuss health beliefs here, not in answers and not in comments. So please don't take a position on whether salt consumption is good or bad. 2) don't answer in comments - if you mean to list reasons for the salt content in cheese, please do so in an answer. Even if your information is incomplete, or you're uncertain that it's correct.

@rumtscho "if your information is incomplete, or you're uncertain that it's correct" -- what I'm used to is that's when you comment, and don't answer. Still can be useful, but well, your choice.

For those who are interested in the health factor, we have a sister site Medical Sciences, like Are all salts equally bad for you?

@DanMašek I know that intuitively, it seems like a good idea, so people start doing it. In reality, it has several negative side effects on the network's mechanisms, so it's undesirable and we moderators are supposed to go after every such comment. (I admit we don't get them all). For the network policy, see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533 (it's a historical artefact that it's on the RPG meta).

"we don't discuss health beliefs here, not in answers and not in comments." - then why would we permit assertions about health beliefs in questions?

@KarlKnechtel the OP comes with their own health beliefs, and we can answer the question according to these beliefs, no matter whether we agree with them or not. It's similar to how the Christianity site has questions asking 'according to Greek orthodoxy, how does one do X properly' or similar - exactly because beliefs differ and it's useful to know the perspective from which the OP is coming.

@DanMašek: please see a) the help on (not) commenting and b) the definition of what constitutes an answer (even if the definition is given in a different context). In short: half-answers are ok, answers in comments, even half-answers are not. Neither is new policy.

Since there was some controversy around the way in which the OP's health beliefs were stated, I changed them into more neutral wording, highlighting more of their subjectivity. They are still left in there, as a background motivation to the question.

Salt plays several important roles in cheese making. Certainly flavor enhancement is chief among them, but it also works as a preservative (cheese making is a preservation process, after all).  It also draws moisture from the curd and facilitates textural development.  Finally, salt helps slow and regulate the fermentation process so that proper flavors develop.
There are many types of cheese, of course, and yes, some varieties can be made without salt.  However, salt is a critical ingredient in the vast majority of cheeses.

Salt in cheesemaking serves five major purposes:

Preservation (same as for salted meat products).
Control of water content in the curd (high salt will draw water out of the curd).
Regulation of fermentation (almost every thing used for fermentation of cheese is salt sensitive, so high salt means less fermentation).
Regulation of pH (higher salt helps buffer against changes in pH). This feeds in to both the point above about regulation of fermentation and also affects the chemistry of any aging process the cheese undergoes.
Flavor enhancement.

It’s important to note that salt is not always added during the cheesemaking process, it also comes from the milk itself (whole milk actually has a relatively high salt content to begin with, and some cheesemaking techniques tend to concentrate the salt content), and in some cases from some of the processes involved in making the cheese (some types of fermentation or aging naturally produce some amount of salt as a byproduct).
It’s also important to note that salt content varies widely by variety of cheese, and even within varieties. For example, xynomizithra (known simply as ‘mizithra’ outside of Greece) has an extremely high salt content even compared to other cheeses (easily as high as 500mg in a 30g serving), while mascarpone often has a particularly low salt content (as low as 10mg per 30g serving). Most cheeses are somewhere in the 100-200mg per 30g range though, which is a sizable percentage of the suggested daily values for a healthy adult.

Nice answer except for the chemistry. (1) Salt, NaCl does not and can not act as a pH buffer. An effective aqueous pH buffer system must include a salt made from a strong acid and weak base or weak acid and strong base. NaCl combines a strong acid and base, hence no buffering. If salt regulates pH it is through regulation of fermentation and the acids that fermentation produces, not buffering. (2) NaCl is not a byproduct of fermentation. Total mass of salt in a wheel of cheese does not increase or decrease with aging. Salt concentration can rise by loss of water, not by fermentation.

I'm writing up a couple of side points, additionally to the main ones which have been discussed in Austin Hemmelgarn's answer.
Natural salt content
Some of the salt is already there. Cows are mammals, and their body fluids contain a certain amount of salt. When you take 400 ml of milk, and make 100 g of cheese out of them (a typical proportion for a semihard cheese), you end up with 0.5 g of salt per 100 g of cheese. This is pretty much the minimum amount of salt which you're always going to have in there.
Almost all cheese also has salt added, but not all. I've actually had cheese made without extra salt, one of the larger supermarket brand organic Edamer used to be 0.5 per 100 g, but they've changed it by now to be more in the 0.7 to 1.0 range. The taste was somewhat unaccustomed, but I liked it well enough.
It may be all about taste, after all
As the other answer described, the salt has a lot of functions related to fermentation conditions, preservation and texture. It turns out that it's not the NaCl alone that can fulfill these functions, and there are, every now and again, people who attempt to make low-sodium cheese with alternative salts, such as potassium chloride. The cheese then hits all these desired points - but it also has a highly unusual taste, which most people dislike at first bite. So, strictly speaking, taste is the limiting factor which makes us use sodium chloride in cheese, specifically. The twist is that you still can't use less salt if you're OK with a less salty taste.
Young cheeses are irrelevant to the discussion
This is actually contained in the other answer if you read between the lines. Your statement that "at least the simple young cheeses can be made perfectly well without any salt" is misleading in this context, because young cheeses are different from mature cheeses in every way that's relevant to salting. They undergo a different fermentation (if any), they retain much more water, and they are highly perishable. So, they can be made without salt - but other cheeses need it.

"Cows are mammals" ...and not all cheeses are made from cow's milk.

@FeRD But all milk comes from mammals. Anything else is just an imitation, and so are products made from it.

Well, yes, of course. You can't milk an almond! But goat milk & cheese is quite common, among others.

In cheese, salt has purposes beyond just taste. By preventing unwanted microbial development, which affects the texture and time of the cheese, it aids in control of the fermenting process. It also helps with moisture retention, which effects shelf life and consistency of the cheese. Although certain cheeses might be created without salt, commercial cheese usually has more levels for these practical uses as well as for improving taste and increasing shelf life.I hope you got the answer!

Some salt is already naturally in the cow's milk. Salt is a preserving agent, otherwise the cheese would go bad.
It is also used as a flavour enhancer.
